# "Can't open perl script "t/spec/fudgeall": File or directory not found"

Tags: testing, raku, rakudo

I am trying to run some tests for Rakudo following [instructions in the `README.md`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo), that is, with perl Configure.pl and make. However, when I run

```
make t/02-rakudo/09-thread-id-after-await.t
```

after that, it writes:

```
/home/jmerelo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.0/bin/perl tools/build/check-nqp-version.pl /home/jmerelo/Code/forks/perl6/rakudo/install/bin/nqp-m
rm -f -- perl6
cp -- perl6-m perl6
chmod -- 755 perl6
/home/jmerelo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.0/bin/perl t/harness5 --fudge --moar --keep-exit-code --verbosity=1 t/02-rakudo/09-thread-id-after-await.t
Can't open perl script "t/spec/fudgeall": No existe el archivo o el directorio
Files=0, Tests=0,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.01 CPU)
Result: NOTESTS
```

That directory does not even exist. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `fudgeall` script that the `make` target depends on comes from the spectests repository. To obtain that, run:

```
make spectest_checkout
```

Comment: The testing section of that documentation in fact talks exclusively about running the spectests, not the sanity tests (I suspect the `make` rule probably works for those as much by accident as by design); the first command it suggests, `make spectest`, will automatically do that clone, however.

Comment: @jnthn but I was just trying to follow instructions to run a single test, the ones I had changed... Maybe it would be a good idea to mention that in that case.

Comment: @jjmerelo Sure, I'll happily merge a PR that makes it say whatever would have made it more helpful to you.